# Memory Mapped File into a WPF grid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, large-files, memory-mapped-files

I am working with a large file (8 GB) through a memory mapped file (C# MemoryMappedFile). I would like to be able to put the contents into a WPF grid (data grid for example), but i am having trouble because every approach that seems to work has to load the file into memory, which defeats the point of the memory mapped file.

I know a wpf data grid can access only the data needed, but how do i link it to the memory mapped file so that i can request only the bytes that are being viewed and not have to put the whole thing into memory.

I was hoping for an easy way like datagrid.itemsource = file but that doesn't look like the case.

My end goal is to load this large file and display the bytes of the file, like a hex editor. Anyone have an example using a memory mapped file or something only reads the bytes form the file that the user is viewing?

Comment: Why do you want to use DataGrid? What will you display in columns?

Comment: The columns will be dynamic to create rows of bytes. Similar to most hex editors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to give you a high level overview of how this can be done. You will need both UI virtualization and data virtualization. UI virtualization you have for free in default DataGrid (VirtualizingStackPanel), for data virtualization you have to use custom solutions (example: https://alphachitech.wordpress.com/2015/01/31/virtualizing-observable-collection/). Each item will represent say 1MB of raw data, so in total you will have about 8000 such items in your grid. Initially none of those items actually contains data. Data is only read from your memory mapped file when user scrolls down to that portion of the file (see data virtualization above). This will allow user to scroll whole 8GB file like it's loaded in memory, while really 1MB chunks will be loaded and unloaded while he scrolls.

Comment: That was exactly what i needed. I followed their example and I am able to display large files with minimal impact (10-20MB)

Comment: That was exactly what i needed. I followed their example and I am able to display large files with minimal impact (10-20MB)